# usepackage{tikz-cd} vs usetikzlibrary{cd}

Tags: tikz-cd

Is there a difference between using the package tikz-cd and using the cd tikz library and loading tikz directly?

I can't find the answer in the documentation of either package.

Comment: It's one of the first things written in the `tikz-cd` manual actually. Chapter 1 starts with "To invoke this package in Latex, type `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` or load TikZ and then type `\usetikzlibrary{cd}`". In  other words, they're equivalent.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. That doesn't necessarily mean they do the exact same thing though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No (practical) difference. The code (excluding copyright comment lines) in `tikz-cd.sty` is:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{tikz-cd}[2014/10/30 v0.9e Commutative diagrams with tikz]
\RequirePackage{tikz}[2013/12/13] % pgf version 3.0.0 required
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\endinput
```

so it just loads Ti*k*Z and then does `\usetikzlibrary{cd}`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This is just a pedantic comment: there *can* be differences.

This is an admittedly nasty example.

This code works<sup>1</sup>:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{\edef\pgfmathresult{1}}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

This code does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{\edef\pgfmathresult{1}}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

However, this works<sup>1</sup> again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{\edef\pgfmathresult{1}}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

It is absolutely true that this is not a very useful code, and I have just designed the second code to crash. It does, however, show that there is a technical difference between loading `tikz` and then the `cd` library among other libraries (which could in principle do something along the lines of `\pgfmathdeclarefunction*{axis_height}{0}{\edef\pgfmathresult{1}}`), or later, and loading `tikz-cd`, which forces a certain ordering of loading of the libraries.

Of course, the `cd` library is, even though it is not part of pgf, a standard library and the authors of other libraries will most likely look at the `cd` code to make sure that they do not do harm to it, though it is not inconceivable that someone else may want to define function with the name `axis_height`. Nevertheless, if one is very strict, one has to say that it can, at least in principle, make a difference whether one load the `tikz-cd` package or the `cd` library. As I said, this is just an extended comment, but it does show that one cannot be absolutely sure that there is no difference.

<sub><sup>1</sup> "Works" means you do not get an error when you compile the snippet. You should definitely *not* overwrite the function `axis_height` if you actually want to use the `cd` library.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, in ConTeXt the tikz-cd module is not available, you need to do:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[cd]
```